# Fixed home page

Tags: homepage

I am new to Wordpress. Forgive me if this is a simple question. How do I make a fixed (static) part (section) on the front page (home page) of WordPress site before the blog part?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Welcome to WordPress Stack Exchange. If [this answer](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/45114/73) solves your issue, I close this question here as a duplicate. Would that be okay?

Answer (score 1):

You can set static home page from Admin -> Settings -> Reading.

Check WordPress codex page for more detailed information. http://codex.wordpress.org/Creating_a_Static_Front_Page

Answer (score 0):

First you need to go to the Pages > Add New and create a page that will serve as your home page (typically title "Home"), and add some basic content so that you know if it's showing up or not. Also, create a second page that you want to use to display your blog posts (usually title "Blog"). After that's done, head on down to the Settings > Reading and at the top you should see an option to set a static home page and also a blog page.

Hope this helps, write back if you have further questions :)

Answer (score 0):

Since it sounds more like you want the standard blog template loop to display below the static content (and NOT use a static page), you could edit your home.php template (or copy index.php to home.php) to either echo or include the static content before the blog display loop (ie generally before the line with `while(has_posts)`, eg.

```
include('staticcontent.html');
echo "WELCOME!<br>";

while(has_posts()) ......
```

(and create a child theme if you don't have one so you don't lost this on theme update.)